# Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 36 Invalid column name 'FHID'

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a error on the outer select query invalid column name because even thought I already call the table name in the inner select query.

```
select 
    FHID, 
    sum(case DHSTAT when 'FA' then cnt else 0 end) as 'For Approval',
    sum(case DHSTAT when 'APPRVD' then cnt else 0 end) as 'Approved',
    sum(case DHSTAT when 'CL' then cnt else 0 end) as 'Closed',
    sum(case DHSTAT when 'CRT' then cnt else 0 end) as 'Created',
    sum(case DHSTAT when 'CNL' then cnt else 0 end) as 'Cancelled',
    sum(case DHSTAT when 'RJCT' then cnt else 0 end) as 'Rejected'
from (
    select 
        a.FHID 'From ID' , a.FHVER 'Version', a.FHNAM 'Form Name', 
        convert(Varchar, a.FHCDT, 101) 'Created Date', 
        a.FHCUNAM 'Created by', a.FHDEPT 'Dept.', 
        Cast(count(b.DHSTAT) as Varchar) as cnt
    from 
        tblDWorks_FormHeader a 
    inner join 
        tblDWorks_DataHeader b on a.FHID = b.FHID
    group by 
        a.FHID, a.FHVER, a.FHNAM, a.FHCDT, a.FHCUNAM, a.FHDEPT
) grp
```

I'm expecting to see this kind of result

[image]

Comment: As per the question guide, please do not post images of code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text.

Comment: That image is apparently the result of the inner query. It doesn't have the columns you use in the outer query

Comment: You also need a GROUP BY clause at the end.

Comment: And don't try to SUM varchar data, keep cnt as integer.

Answer (score 1):

In the inner query, you use an alias for FHID as 'From ID'. You have to utilize the same alias while selecting from the outer query.